# Ingest data into databricks using Rest API (Scala)

Tags: scala, rest, databricks, azure-databricks

I need to make a call to a rest API from databricks preferably using Scala to get the data and persist the same in databricks. This is the first time i am doing this and I need help. Can any of you please walk me through step by step as to how to achieve this?. The API team has already created a service principal and has given access to the API. So the authentication needs to be done through SPN.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

REST API is not recommended approach to ingest data into databricks.

**Reason:** The amount of data uploaded by single API call cannot exceed 1MB.

To upload a file that is larger than 1MB to DBFS, use the streaming API, which is a combination of create, addBlock, and close.

Here is an example of how to perform this action using Python.

```
import json
import base64
import requests

DOMAIN = '<databricks-instance>'
TOKEN = b'<your-token>'
BASE_URL = 'https://%s/api/2.0/dbfs/' % (DOMAIN)

def dbfs_rpc(action, body):
  """ A helper function to make the DBFS API request, request/response is encoded/decoded as JSON """
  response = requests.post(
    BASE_URL + action,
    headers={"Authorization: Bearer %s" % TOKEN },
    json=body
  )
  return response.json()

# Create a handle that will be used to add blocks
handle = dbfs_rpc("create", {"path": "/temp/upload_large_file", "overwrite": "true"})['handle']
with open('/a/local/file') as f:
  while True:
    # A block can be at most 1MB
    block = f.read(1 << 20)
    if not block:
        break
    data = base64.standard_b64encode(block)
    dbfs_rpc("add-block", {"handle": handle, "data": data})
# close the handle to finish uploading
dbfs_rpc("close", {"handle": handle})
```

For more details, refer "[DBFS API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/dbfs?toc=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fazure-databricks%2FTOC.json&bc=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fbread%2Ftoc.json)"

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Sujatha, If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

the above code will work, in case if you want to upload jar file or non-ascii file instead of
dbfs_rpc("add-block", {"handle": handle, "data": data})
use
dbfs_rpc("add-block", {"handle": handle, "data": data.decode('UTF8')})

rest of the details are same.